# Can Pytorch autograd compute gradient with respect to only one parameter in neural network?

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, neural-network, gradient

I am trying to find the gradient of Loss function with respect to its neural network (specifically gradient of one node in neural net).

Due to my special type of problem, I only want to compute the gradient with respect to one node in neural network. For example, say we have Loss (L) and neural network parameters theta. Then, I only want to find dL/dTheta_1 where theta_1 is the any ONE node in the neural net.

We typically use `grad = torch.autograd.grad(Loss, parameters())` to find gradients of dL/dTheta = [dL/dTheta_1, dL/dTheta_2 ... dL/dTheta_n] but I only want dL/dTheta_1 to reduce the computational cost.

Would it be possible to code it with Pytorch?

Theoretically, I think it is possible to compute only one gradient component but I am not sure Pytorch has the option for that.

Does anyone have a idea on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by a node you mean a single component of a weight tensor, I think it can't be done. Pytorch uses forward graph to perform backward pass, so it can calculate gradients only for graph elements, which `theta[0]` is not. You could try using autograd to get gradients of outputs of all operations that use `theta` directly and compute `dL/dTheta_1` yourself from them by chain rule. Or you could "chip off" `Theta_1` during forward pass from other components and process it separately, which would reduce efficiency of forward pass. But keep in mind that if there are several layers between `Theta` and `L`, you can't avoid calculating their full gradients, so it's unlikely you'll save much time.